# Interpretation of the convergence in the mean square sense

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I'm new to the notion of convergence in the mean square (or convergence in $L^2$). So, I want to ask about the intuition/interpretation of an algorithm whose iterates converge in the mean square to a certain value, say I have the following:
$$ \underset{k \rightarrow \infty}{\lim} \mathbb{E}\left[\|x_k - x^*\|^2\right] = 0, \label{eq.1}\tag{1}$$
In the deterministic world (without the expectation), I could say that $x_k$ converges to $x^*$ but at least to my understanding in the probabilistic world convergence in $L^2$ does not imply convergence almost surely and I fail to interpret Eq. (\ref{eq.1}).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the bias-variance decomposition of the mean squared error (that is, the $L^2$ norm), we have that convergence in $L^2$ is equivalent to the bias and the variance vanishing. Intuitively, this means that as $n\to\infty$, the distribution of $x_n$ will become more and more concentrated around $x^*$.

Something that may also be useful, is that convergence in mean squared implies convergence in probability.